# Using extensions/plugins/addons with a headless browser

Tags: testing, phantomjs, browser-extension, headless-browser

Is there a way to run automatic tests, using a headless browser (i.e. PhantomJS, Selenium) that loads browser extensions/plugins/addons?

More specifically, I'd like to simulate the effects of ad-blockers (like Ghostery, ad-block+) on my code, to see if they break it.

I saw PhantomJS does not support the Flash plugin since 2012, but was wondering if there's a way to still simulate said conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, shoehorning plugins into server side browsers is near impossible, or not recommended.

I've overcome my problem by using client-side unit tests (using QUnit), but I believe the original issue can be solved by adding firewall/iptable rules that block specific urls that serve ads, on the machine used for testing.

The list of blocked urls can be taken from the ad-blocker plugins themselves, and updated regularly.